# Key mapping that will invoke the wildmenu

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, normal-mode

I'm trying to create a key mapping that makes switching buffers quicker and easier - something like:

```
set wildmenu
nnoremap <Tab> :buffer<space><Tab>
```

The problem is, this mapping leaves me at the end of a command line that looks like:

```
:buffer ^I
```

when I want it to start tabbing through the list of buffers.

I've searched the help files and Google, and tried many different combinations of `:execute` and `:normal`, all to no avail. Is there a way to do what I'm asking, or am I stuck with the following, two-keypress solution?

```
set wildmenu
nnoremap <Tab> :buffer<space>
```

Then, pressing `<Tab><Tab>` will do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `set wildcharm=<Tab>` and the following mapping will do what you want:

```
nnoremap <Tab> :buffer <Tab>
```

See [`:h 'wildcharm'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27wildcharm%27) and [`:h 'wildchar'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27wildchar%27):

- `wildchar` defines the key which triggers the wildmenu
- `wildcharm` is like `wildchar` but it works in macros and mappings.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `wildcharm` option:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
nnoremap <key> :buffer<Space><C-z>
```

See `:help 'wildcharm`.

Comment: Seems like we get the same answer at some seconds of difference :-) But I have a question: Why do you suggest to use `<C-z>` as `wildcharm` and not `<Tab>` as OP wanted? Is it just a personal preference or is there another reason?

Comment: 1. That's the value suggested in the doc. 2. `wildcharm` is only used in mappings anyway so it makes sense to use a *special* value to prevent confusion.

Comment: My concern was more about incompatibility with other modes or this kind of stuff but your points make sense indeed.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl. statox beat you by only a minute. I went with the <Tab> as my wildcharm character